# Assign a value to a variable in private section of class in C++

Tags: c++, class, private

How can you assign a variable in the private section of a class in C++?

I tried to do it the following way:

```
private:
    std::string foo;
    foo = "randomValue";
```

But that results in an error message.

Though if I declare and assign a value to the variable at once, like this:

```
private:
    std::string foo = "randomValue";
```

it works.

Why does the second way work but the first one not?

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Comment: The first way doesn't work because `foo = "randomValue";` is a plain non-declaration statement. Such statements can only be inside functions. You would have the same problem if you tried to do it outside a class, in the global scope. And to be perhaps brutally honest, any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned it.

Comment: `foo = "randomValue";` is assignment, not initialization. Initialization is when you set a value right when creating an object.

Comment: First one is invalid syntax and the second one is. And so is `std::string foo{"randomValue"};`

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't get the answer completely. Is the second way correct or not (at least it works for me)? And if it is not, why is it so bad?

Comment: `private: std::string foo = "randomValue";` works because it is not an assignment. It is called a [_default member initializer_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) and it just instructs the compiler on what to do if that member is not mentioned in the initializer list of a constructor.

Comment: @luux -- *How can you assign a variable in the private section of a class in C++?* -- But didn't you already do this successfully in your second attempt?  You answered your own question.  What advantage did you see in the (incorrect) syntax in your first attempt over the second attempt?  IMO, that's the only reason I see for the question, and that is you actually wanted to do something additional besides assigning/initializing a value to a member variable, and the compiler error prevented you from doing whatever it is.

Comment: Yes the second is correct syntax.  That's why you get compilation errors on the first one. Here is a lesson on it on learncpp.com https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/default-member-initialization/ (maybe you will find that site useful)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thank you for the lesson. I'll definitely have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case the comments don't make it clear (I found them a bit fragmented):

```
std::string foo = "randomValue";
```

is (as you yourself say) *initialisation*.  It initialises `foo` when the object is constructed.  It works from C++11 on and is, IMO, the right way to do it (because you can initialise all your member variables in the same place, so if you subsequently add one, you're not going to forget).

Whereas:

```
std::string foo;
foo = "randomValue";
```

if it were legal, would be *assignment* - i.e. it assigns a value to a variable that already exists.  But you can only do that in the body of a function (including the constructor).

Comment: Hi Paul. While your answer is technically correct, can you give a reference to the standard where this is mentioned? *”if it were legal, would be assignment - i.e. it assigns a value to a variable that already exists. But you can only do that in the body of a function (including the constructor).”*

Comment: Sorry, no.  I find the standard to be pretty impenetrable, tbh, and only refer to it when there is no alternative.  Maybe someone smarter than me can help.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `foo = "randomValue";` is not a declaration it's an initialization. The reason this is significant (and this is heavily summarizing) when you create a class, anything that's not inside a function is intended to be a declaration (allocating memory, etc.) and everything inside a function is more "processing" instructions such as initializations. Typically the best thing to do is to declare and then initialize in instructor such as:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string foo; //valid decleration in MyClass's scope
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        foo = "randomValue"; //constructor assigns value
    }
};
```

The reason this happens is also similar to how you can't assign things later outside of a function's scope (i.e. global).
For example you can't run this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
std::string foo; //valid declaration in global scope
foo = "hi"; //invalid initialization, can't be global.

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo;
}
```

but you can run this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
std::string foo; //valid global declaration

int main()
{
    foo = "hi"; //valid initialization
    std::cout << foo;
}
```

If at all helps, the difference between declaration and initialization, is that declaration creates the container (memory address/location) an the initialization sets that actual contents of that container. For reference, this is why if you just declare a variable and print it, you get (typically) gibberish, as it's what's at that memory address at the moment since it has not yet been replaced with whatever you want to initialize it as.

Comment: Using a *mem-initializer* is better than assigning in the constructor.

Comment: *The short answer is that `foo = "randomValue";` is not a declaration it's an initialization.* no it is an assignment.

Comment: ah you're right @ChukwujiobiCanon